# Dot net Framework vs dot net core sdk

Tags: .net, .net-core, sdk, frameworks

I want to know the difference between:

1. dot net framework vs dot net core SDK
2. IDE (visual studio) vs Editor (VS Code)
3. Dot net core SDK contains the dot net core framework or not
4. It is possible to develop a full (dot net MVC) web application with VS code

Kindly clarify my doubts

Comment: Most questions should be answered with the article [Choose between ASP.NET 4.x and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/choose-aspnet-framework) from the asp.net core documentation. Which is a good starting point for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what you want to hear, but .NET Core is younger and more modern than .NET Framework. 
The core is also, generally speaking, more lean than Framework. Core got rid of many deprecated technologies like Remoting so not everything that worked in Framework will work in Core. Some features of Framework are going to be implemented in Core in the future like WPF which will be available from Core 3.0 on. 
One important point is that Core is a cross-platform i.e. you can run Core programs on Linux and Mac too. This does not apply to ever Library. WPF will still only be available for Windows.
If you need more detailed information you can check out the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/) and compare.

For the IDE: I've never really worked with VS Code, but the IDE should make no difference in what programs you can develop. If you take care of compilation yourself, you could develop with plain notepad. It would be a pain though. I'd suggest to try both and decide based on your personal preferences.

MVC is a pattern that is independent of language or IDE. But if you want to be the view in WPF you will need to use either Framework or Core 3.0. I don't know how well the VS Code supports you with WPF.

I hoped this helped a little

Comment: VSCode is much lighterweight than Visual studio. Has better support for other language since you can just download plugins for Go, Python  or whatever language. Debugging depends on the plugin you've got.

Visual Studio is much better if you're sticking solely to C# imo, VS Code is better if you're doing JS or Python or whatever. 

As for MVC, I dont think debugging in VSCode is as easy since there is some set up for IIS, but maybe its easier now than it used to be.